# ParseException - Can't figure out the right pattern

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat, parseexception

I have the following string: `dateToParse = "Fri May 16 23:59:59 BRT 2014"`, and want to parse it using DateFormat:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.getDefault());
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(dateToParse));
```

right now I'm trying it with `pattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"`, but get this exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri May 16 23:59:59 BRT 2014" (at offset 0)
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with this pattern, specially at index 0... any idea what am I missing? Thanks.

[EDIT]
So part of the problem was I was using Locale.getDefault(), so problably trying to parse a date in english with a dateFormat in portuguese... with the correct Locale, I'm still getting ParseException, but this time at offset 20, which means something is going wrong when parsing the timezone ('BRT', in my case)...

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a leading space or some other character in the  String you are attempting to parse. I wrote up a quick sample using the same DateFormat as you and it worked without issue

Comment: @Mena I'm editing the question, sry

Answer (score 1):

its probably because of the Locale.

Try changing

```
Locale.getDefault()
```

to

```
Locale.ENGLISH
```

like this

```
        String date_ = "Fri May 16 23:59:59 BRT 2014";
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
    dateFormat.setCalendar(date);
    try {
        date.setTime(dateFormat.parse(date_));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Ok, when using Locale.ENGLISH I get the same exception, but this time at offset 20... so I suppose I'm using the "z" pattern the wrong way, any hint on this?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this pattern works for you "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy" if not take a look at his site 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Ex:

```
String pattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.getDefault());
        Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            d.setTime(dateFormat.parse(String.valueOf(d)));
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block


e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: doesn't works. I've checked that page before building the pattern. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?
The code ran fine in my machine

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String date = "Fri May 16 23:59:59 BRT 2014";
        String pattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.getDefault());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
        cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(date));


}
```