# Getting UTC time with Calendar and Date

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I'm trying to get an instance of Date with UTC time using the following code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date now = cal.getTime();
```

that looks so simple, but if I check the values at IntelliJ's debugger, I get different dates for `cal` and `now`:

`cal`:java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1405690214219,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=GMT,firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=6,WEEK_OF_YEAR=29,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=199,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=1,**HOUR_OF_DAY=13**,MINUTE=30,SECOND=14,MILLISECOND=219,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]

`now`:Fri Jul 18 10:30:14 BRT 2014

as you can see, `cal` is 3 hours ahead of `now`... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] Looks like `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` before the code above does the job...

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posing a duplicate question. Duplicates dilute the quality of the site and waste people's time.

Answer (score 5):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349475/calendar-getinstancetimezone-gettimezoneutc-is-not-returning-utc-time)

The System.out.println(cal_Two.getTime()) invocation returns a Date from getTime(). It is the Date which is getting converted to a string for println, and that conversion will use the default IST timezone in your case.

You'll need to explicitly use DateFormat.setTimeZone() to print the Date in the desired timezone.

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
   new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);

System.out.println("Time zone: " + timeZone.getID());
System.out.println("default time zone: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
System.out.println();

System.out.println("UTC:     " + simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
System.out.println("Default: " + calendar.getTime());
```

Edit To convert cal to date

```
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
      int day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
      System.out.println(year);
      Date date = new Date(year - 1900, month, day);  // is same as date = new Date();
```

Just build the Date object using the Cal values. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Ok, I saw a few answers like this. Your code works, but I want an instance of date, and not to print it. If I try something like `Date now = simpleDateFormat.parse(calendar.getTime().toString());` I get a ParseException... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914287/parseexception-cant-figure-out-the-right-pattern

Answer (score 2):

Try using a date formatter and set the time zone to UTC.

```
dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: Can you show me the proper way to use `dateFormatter.parse()`? I'm looking for a Date instance, not a String...